# Obtener Huella SHA1 Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sha1, keystore

Tengo mi archivo .keystore con el que firmé una app que ya subí a Play Store.

En una nueva app que estoy haciendo y que usa servicios de firebase, me puede la huella SHA1.

Googleando que encontrado esta web: https://mscdroidlabs.es/como-obtener-la-huella-digital-sha1-de-tu-app/ que lo explica bastante bien, el problema es que yo no tengo el fichero .jks por ningún lado.

¿Cómo puedo obtener el certificado SHA1 a partir del archivo .keystore para poder subir mi app a la play store sin problema y utilizar los servicios de Firebase?

Perdón si la pregunta es tonta pero es que me hago mucho lío con los almacenes de llaves de Java y Android.

Gracias por vuestra paciencia y tiempo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**¿Cómo obtener el certificado SHA1 a partir del archivo .keystore?**

Puedes usar la utilería `Keytool` para obtener el `SHA1` de tu Keystore, para acceder a esta utilería primero debes acceder mediante linea de comandos a el directorio que contiene Java y su directorio \bin donde se encuentra `Keytool.exe`:

```
cd %JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

posteriormente esta es la forma de listar las propiedades del Keystore incluyendo el SHA1, debes definir la ruta de tu Keystore y el alias definido:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "<keystore path>" -alias "<alias name>"
```

este comando te requerirá el password y posteriormente desplegará las propiedades.

ejemplo:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Data\Development Android\KEYSTORE\totita.keystore" -alias "puisor"
```

de esta forma podrás visualizar el valor del SHA-1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]