# Puedo usar el mismo SHA1 en dos proyectos diferentes?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, sha1, sha256

Estoy usando otro proyecto (ya en playstore) como plantilla para adaptar otra app de otra temática, la cosa es que necesito darle login con firebase y me pide SHA1, pero ese SHA1 lo usé en el otro proyecto ya en produccion.

Como puedo cambiar el SHA1 de mi segundo proyecto? o en caso tal, que pasa si uso el mismo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Más allá de si hay validaciones o no, reusar un keystore significa que, si se compromete ese certificado y toca revocarlo, todo lo que haya utilizado ese keystore debe actualizarse para usar otro certificado. Es cosa de generar otro certificado y guardarlo en otro keystore.

Comment: Hola Mr K. no debes tener problema usando el mismo SHA-1 de tu Keystore, No es práctico ni recomendable "que uses una firma diferente por cada app", no es necesario usar un almacen de claves (.jks o .keystore) para cada app. Lo que no es correcto es usar el Keystore de depuración (debug.keystore), revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el SHA1 para varios proyectos, esto no debe ser problema, de hecho puedes tener un certificado para firmar todas tus aplicaciones de tu cuenta de desarrollador.

> Como puedo cambiar el SHA1 de mi segundo proyecto? o en caso tal, que
> pasa si uso el mismo?

Si deseas cambiar el SHA1, debes usar otro almacen de claves (archivo .keystore) ya que este tendrá una SHA1 diferente. Si usas el mismo no hay absolutamente ningún problema, de hecho la mayoría de los desarrolladores trabajan con un .keystore y no es recomendable crear un .keystore para obtener un SHA1 distinto para ser usado en cada aplicación.

---

Algo muy importante, veo que estas usando el keystore : `debug.keystore`, este es un  Keystore de debug que Android Studio genera automáticamente en:

```
C:\Users\<username>\.android\debug.keystore
```

este no debería ser usado para producción, por esta razón:

> **El certificado autofirmado sirve para firmar una app que se va a depurar, y la fecha de vencimiento es 30 días a partir de la fecha de
> creación. Una vez que venza el certificado, se mostrará un error de
> compilación.**

Android Studio volverá a generar un almacén de claves y una clave de depuración nuevos, por lo tanto ya no podrás realizar actualizaciones de tu aplicación porque tu keystore sera diferente.

Lo ideal es que hubiera realizado tu propio Keystore

[**Genera una clave de carga y un almacén de claves.**](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign-apk)

Revisa también:

[Cómo obtener SHA-1 para producción](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/153220/95)

[Obtener Huella SHA1 Android Studio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/436219/obtener-huella-sha1-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

En teoría se puede usar el mismo SHA1 para multiples apps, ya que este no está ligado a una app específica, es solamente la firma que usas.

De todas maneras te recomendaría que uses una firma diferente por cada app, aquí tienes los pasos para generar una nueva:

https://flutteragency.com/how-to-generate-sha-1-in-flutter/